# how to scrape instagram querys using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, instagram

I'm trying for a while now to scrape the plain text of instagram's posts query ("https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/query_id=17888483320059182&id=USER_ID&first=50") and get only 403 and 301 responses.
anyone knows how can i bypass these responses or scrape the data?

Comment: Apart from requesting that URL, you need to add all the headers that the website is expecting. That includes User Agent, and some special auth headers.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram blocks requests with the [default Scrapy User-Agent](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent).

You can change the User-Agent of Scrapy so it will use one that looks like a real browser. But you will still have problems scraping Instagram, as commented in [this discussion](https://github.com/snarfed/bridgy/issues/665): requests limits etc.

I remind you that [scraping Instagram is against their TOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/71p3x6/using_instagram_scraper_as_a_part_of_my_app_is_it/), so they will eventually block your account and/or IP if the scraping is detected.

Answer (score 1):

It will be quite hard to get it working using Scrapy because of the way it works. If you really want to scrape data from Instaram, I would recommend you using [onegram](https://github.com/pauloromeira/onegram), which is a Instagram Python API-like bot powered by [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests).